# How to close the session in asp.net if computer idle for 5 mins

Tags: asp.net

I m developing web application using ASP.NET and I want to close the current user session if the computer is idle for 5 minutes. Idle not means for web application only, Its full system that means if no keystroke received from keyboard for 5 mins.

I got some info thru Google about Idle Tracker in VC++ but I dont know how to use that DLL in my web application. Link here.

Please guide me how to achieve this. I want to get the total computer active time and idle time thru asp.net for my employees productivity report.

Comment: I've voted to close this, and I note that Stack Overflow is a MUCH more appropriate site for programming questions. As with any question on SE, giving information on what you have tried, what works... and maybe posting an actual link would help - "link here" kind of dosen't do any one any good if there is no, actual, link.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on how your controlling the session, but I would be looking at the web.config section

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

This allows you to specify a timeout and a view to return to when timed out.